# manipulate a pandas dataframe to combine like columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large pandas dataframe that looks like this i am using for a relational table (with several thousand lines, and the number of activities vary for each trail_id):

[image: table_1]

and I want it to be formed like this:

[image: table 2]

I have tried both of these and it does not seem to work:

```
pd.melt(df)
df.stack().reset_index()
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ``dataframe1.set_index('trail_id').stack().rename('activity_id').droplevel(-1).reset_index()``? The `melt` answer below is the simplest though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `id_vars` to `.melt()` to get the output you want.

```
>>> df.melt(id_vars='trail_id', value_name='activity_id').drop(columns='variable')
    trail_id  activity_id
0          1            1
1          2            1
2          3            1
3          4            3
4          5            2
5          1            2
6          2            2
7          3            2
8          4            4
9          5            5
10         1            3
11         2            4
12         3            6
13         4            7
14         5            9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do bellow code:

```
import pandas as pd
# Initializing
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame({'trail_id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                           'activity_1':[1,1,1,3,2],
                           'activity_2':[2,2,2,4,5],
                           'activity_3':[3,4,6,7,9]})
dictionary = dataframe1.to_dict()

# Create the final dictionary to put the values in
main_dict = {"trail_id":[], "activity_id":[]}
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    if(key == "trail_id"):
        continue
    else:
        main_dict["trail_id"] += list(dictionary["trail_id"].values())
        main_dict["activity_id"] += list(value.values())

# Dropping the index is not necessary but it helps to have a cleaner output
last_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=main_dict).sort_values(by = ["trail_id"]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(last_dataframe)
```

**Output**

```
    trail_id  activity_id
0          1            1
1          1            2
2          1            3
3          2            1
4          2            2
5          2            4
6          3            1
7          3            2
8          3            6
9          4            3
10         4            4
11         4            7
12         5            2
13         5            5
14         5            9
```

Comment: A for loop is not necessary, nor is it efficient in this case

Answer (score 1):

```
df = (
    pd.concat(
        [
            df["trail_id"],
            df.loc[:, "activity_1":"activity_3"].apply(list, axis=1),
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
    .explode(0)
    .rename(columns={0: "activity_id"})
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   trail_id activity_id
0         1           1
0         1           2
0         1           3
1         2           1
1         2           2
1         2           4
2         3           1
2         3           2
2         3           6
3         4           3
3         4           4
3         4           7
4         5           2
4         5           5
4         5           9
```